# How do I read in a text file (containing comma separated numbers) into a list of integers in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, list, text

I have a text file which contains numbers that look like this:

`1,1,4,3,3,4,2,2,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,2,3,4,2,3,3,3,2,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,3`

In my code, I need to go over an array of integers and read them in one by one to perform numeric operations on them. Sort of like this:

```
  dna.each { |a|
    d = dna[a]
    dl << d #adjust dice total as rand_i=>0-5 so add 1 to each dice score
    cl << w[d][i] #add looked up bar number to list
  }
end
```

Where DNA is a list which is: `dna = [1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4]`

However, when I've tried converting this into a list (based on other answers on Stackoverflow), there is always a trailing whitespace like this `3\n`, which I cannot deal with as an integer anymore. This is what I used to read it line by line (since the textfile can be modified to have one number per line):

`File.readlines("a.txt")`

But as I said, this appends a `\n` character to the item, which cannot be dealt as an integer anymore.

How do I make sure that the file is passed into an array of integers where I can access its elements by index?

Comment: after read line replace spaces and newlines then use split and convert to int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the file, get rid of newline, split on commas and translate elements into integers:

```
File.read("a.txt").strip.split(',').map(&:to_i)
```